# Run php code with shortcode wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want use php code in texteditor via shortcode, look like this:

```
<?php if ($a === 1): ?>
<p>Hello world</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>Hi world</p>
<?php endif; ?>
-->
[if $a===1]
<p>Hello world</p>
[else]
<p>Hi world</p>
[/if]
```

or:

```
<?php foreach ($arr as $item): ?>
<p><?php echo $item; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
-->
[foreach $arr as $item]
<p>[echo $item]</p>
[/foreach ]
```

Somebody can help me!

Answer (score -1):

PHP will not be parsed/executed by the text editor for security reasons.

If you want to achieve things like this, some plugins might help you, but you should really consider not doing things like this.